# Is it possible to generate a "View Result Tree" listener, when recording, for each Request Sampler?

Tags: jmeter

When recording a session, I notice a "View Result Tree" listener is added at Thread level. Is it possible to automatically create "View Result Tree" listeners for each request sampler as they are added when the session is recorded.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would perform very badly and would be cumbersome to use.
View Results tree placed as child of Thread group that contains your sampler will receive all sampler responses.

Why do you want to place 1 under each request sampler ?

You can automatically create timers by placing them as children of Test script recorder:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder

Comment: THanks for this. " It would couter performing." Sorry I do not understand this commnet. No doubt a little typo. I just wanted to know whether it could be done, as it would also enable me to enable the addition of other nodes when recording, automatically.